# attempting to create a script that will create a border around specific element when i hover on it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to create a script that will create a border around specific element when i hover on it

the code i attempted this with..

```
(function(){
  $(document.body).each(function(){
$(this).hover(
    function(){
        $(this).css('border','1px solid blue');

    },
    function(){
        $(this).css('border','none');
    }
)
  })
})()
```

any help will be much appreciated

Comment: What is happening when you run the code? What is not working?

Comment: @Jergason It puts a border around the body when hovered.

Comment: aah sorry i guess i should've mentioned that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `delegate` just attach the mouseover/mouseout event to body tag instead of attaching it to all the elements on the page. Using `this` we can control the css.

**Note**: This method is attaching only a single event handler on body element.

```
$(function(){
  $('body').delegate("*", 'mouseover', function(e){
                $(this).css('border','1px solid blue');
                e.stopPropagation();

            }).delegate("*", 'mouseout', function(e){
                $(this).css('border','none');
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
        );

});
```

Working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZyLqQ/)

Comment: wow, this is perfect. as well documented the jquery api is.. i wish there was a better way to search through them.. i didn't even know that delegate and stopPropagation existed

Answer (score 3):

Are you attempting to give a border to every element on a page when its hovered over? If so you can try the following

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/dBQnw/1/)**

```
$(function(){
  $(document.body).find('*').each(function(){
        $(this).hover(
            function(){
                $(this).css('border','1px solid blue');

            },
            function(){
                $(this).css('border','none');
            }
        );
  });
});
```

In your code you were basically saying for each body found add the hover, so the event was tied to the body.

For a specific element, say a `div` with the `id` of test you would do the following,

```
$('#test').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).css('border','1px solid blue');

    },
    function(){
        $(this).css('border','none');
    }
);
```

Heres some info on using [jQuery selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aGetting_Started_with_jQuery#Find_me%3a_Using_selectors_and_events)

Comment: You don't need to execute the empty `$()` function at the end

Comment: hmm.. thanks, this is closer to what i was attempting to do, i am teaching myself jquery, and this was a little small script i was working on. i thought that each function would let me traverse through the DOM tree so i didnt bother using find(*)

Comment: This code will attach hover event handler to all the elements on the page which is not efficient. Use `delegate` instead. Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Why use javascript to just add a hover border on one or more elements?  One can use plain CSS with no programming.

You don't show what your page structure looks like or talk about exactly what you want to have the border, but if you have this HTML:

```
<div class="autoBorder">Some text</div>
```

Then, you can use this CSS to add a border upon mouse hover:

```
.autoBorder:hover {border: 1px solid #00F;}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Eveything in the body
$("body *").hover(function() {
    $(this).css('border', '1px solid blue');

}, function() {
    $(this).css('border', 'none');
});



// Specific Element using an "id"
$("#e").hover(function() {
    $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');

}, function() {
    $(this).css('border', 'none');
});




// Specific elements using a "class"
$(".number").hover(function() {
    $(this).css('border', '1px solid lime');

}, function() {
    $(this).css('border', 'none');
});
```

You can find an example at: http://jsfiddle.net/Shaz/3pfRx/